# Displaying information into a grid

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I've got a button where if I click it, it retrieves player information on a game server.
I need to figure out a way to display this in a grid.

When I do a Console.Write(sendRConCommand("players"))

This is outputted to my console:

```
Players on server:
[#] [IP Address]:[Port] [Ping] [GUID] [Name]
--------------------------------------------------
0   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX    46   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) [FF]Otto
1   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX   109  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) [BBC] Emma Watson
2   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX      46   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) [FF]Miikka
3   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX   46   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) Bops
4   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX      32   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) [BBC] Wesley Snipes
5   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX    31   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) Pierre
6   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX     46   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) bertrand
7   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX     -1   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) SIGGI (Lobby)
8   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX    47   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) Min (Lobby)
9   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX     32   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) Frostpwnz
10  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX   31   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) Zulu BASSA (Lobby)
11  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX     31   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) Zardock (Lobby)
14  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX    63   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(OK) plbmas
(13 players in total)
```

I need to figure out how to display this information in a grid, with the column headers that are shown as well.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you want to display information in WPF Grid or Console App, but make it more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the text into a data structure.  Currently it is all text, so it will be displayed in only one column.

I suggest, you split the data based on carriage returns, then for each player row (line 3 onwards), split the columns.  The following is a rough code outline, edit as required.

```
        // Setup Datatable to hold the information
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("Number", typeof(int)), 
            new DataColumn("IP Address", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Ping", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("GUID", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string))
        });

        // Get info            
        string info = sendRConCommand("players");

        // Split Rows
        string[] infoRows = info.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int start = 3; // ignore first 3 lines
        while (start < infoRows.Length - 1) // Ignore last line
        {
            // Split row on spaces, and remove anything that is an empty space
            string[] row = infoRows[start].Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Number"] = int.Parse(row[0].ToString());
            dr["IP Address"] = row[1].ToString();
            dr["Ping"] = int.Parse(row[2].ToString());
            dr["GUID"] = row[3].ToString();
            int nameItem = 4;
            while (nameItem < row.Length)
            {   // Names can have spaces, so we need to merge
                dr["Name"] += " " + row[nameItem].ToString();
                nameItem++;
            }
            dr["Name"] = dr["Name"].ToString().Trim(); // Trim any leading spaces
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            start++;
        }

        // Job Done
        mygridview.DataSource = dt;
```

Where `mygridview` is your grid.

I have put it all into a data table, but custom objects, list etc would also work.

Comment: This helped a lot, but unfortunately the table isn't populating.

Comment: Any Error messages or is the gridview simply blank?

Comment: Grid is just simply blank :/
I did a Console.Write on the string before it's split
and a Console.Write on the array once it's been splt, and the first outputs the table of players into the console, the second just outputs System.String[]

Comment: The output is as expected - The `Environment.NewLine` might not be doing a split properly. I have tested the code above on a windows pc, with the text directly typed, so it might be different if it's being sent from a remote source.  Try looking the first element in the array after the first split, if the data is still the same, change `Environment.NewLine` to `"\r\n"` or something similar to split the lines.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll look into doing this now and get back if it helps. :)

Comment: I've just tried both of
string[] infoRows = info.Split(new string[] { @"\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

And also string[] infoRows = info.Split(new string[] { @"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Doing a Console.Output(infoRows[1]) was giving me an error, index out of bounds.

Seems like you were right in saying it's not doing the split as it should.

Comment: So I'm doing a Console.WriteLine(infoRows.Length); and it's always returning 1. No matter how I split the string.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the split on lines is not working. I think the `@"\r\n"` should be without the `@`.  If that fails, you might need to convert the text to a char array, to see what character is being used to terminate the line.

Comment: The character just appears to be a blank space on the end of a line.
But it only selects if you drop to the next line :\

Comment: string[] infoRows = WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.playerList.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "{0}",@",
",Environment.NewLine, System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Thanks for all your help, the above code seemed to do the trick, I'd vote you up if I could do so :D

Comment: Cool, you probably don't need all of them, but whatever works :-)

Answer (score 1):

it would depend on how its passed back from the game server... if its from a string then this needs parsing (splitting up) and then arranged into a format that your grid handles..

if its DataGridView (winform) then data source takes in a list<>..

Answer (score 1):

You can specify widths using string.Format like this:

```
string.Format("{0,-10}{1,-10}", "column1", "column2");
```

where the negative is for left-aligned values. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

Comment: Would this work when IPs and Names aren't necessarily always going to be the same length?

Comment: This was an example of how you could format the output yourself. If you need to parse some arbitrary string returned from sendRConCommand and then format it or load it into a grid then you might need a more complex solution. Looks like you could make use of something like this CSV reader to help load into some object format that would be easier to work with: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want WPF grid, do next:

Put `DataGrid` on a form. Set DataGrid's `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `True`.

In code-behind set `dataGrid.ItemsSource = playerInfo` (Array of List)